# Replace all substrings in string c#

Tags: c#, regex

I need to find and replace all "B1:1" in string "A4:1_A1:1_A2:1_A3:2_A4:1_B1:1_B2:2200_"
on "B1:880".

Newbie in regex and need some help with it and Regex.Replace()

Comment: Who upvoted this? Show what you tried please...

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because no attempt shown.

Comment: Please post the code that you've written. Someone will guide you through the corrections needed. If you want to learn regEx, Google it!

Comment: why regex? just string.Replace

Comment: Thanks guys, forget about string.Replace :# need to sleep more :)

Comment: I found this useful and I upvoted it, people who comment, and down vote are elitists who give programmers a bad name. They shouldn't even allow voting without posting answers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`<YourString>.Replace("B1:1", "B1:880");` should do it too, right?

In case of multiple occurrences

```
Regex.Replace( "Your String", @"^B1:1$","B1:880" );
```

Comment: Will also replace `"B1:10"`.

Comment: @TimSchmelter no `B1:10` in given string :P

Comment: @Uriel_SVK: do you think that this is the only possible string?

Comment: @TimSchmelter of course not, on the other hand, he would like to  'replace all "B1:1"' so even the ones in B1:10 :) Thats why i love bad questions

Answer (score 2):

You could use `String.Split` with a little bit LINQ:

```
str = string.Join("_", str.Split('_')
   .Select(s => s == "B1:1" ? "B1:880" : s));
```